# NSNotification in Background thread - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, delegates, nsnotificationcenter

I am working on chat application in which messages are received in delegate method. From delegate method, I am calling NSNotification to update the messages in UI.

//Delegate method

```
- (void)didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"MessageReceived"  object:nil userInfo:@{@"message":message}];
}
```

The above delegate method will be called for every new message that i receive. Suppose If i receive the large number of messages simultaneously, it cause UI to hang. If i add a background thread for a notification, then it will create a new thread for every delegate method call. It is not a good solution. How can i handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting a notification after receiving a message you can directly send message to ViewController responsible for updating UI. For example

```
- (void)didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{
    MessageListController *messageListController; //get reference as per your UI implementation
    [messageListController updateUIWithMessage:message];
}
```

and in updateUIWithMessage method you can write optimised code to update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSOperationQueue` and make it global (class level). Add `NSOperations` to it.

You can use `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property to set the no of max concurrent operations. In this way you can control the multiple operations coming at once. But for you case I think

```
maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

is good. Since you need messages to change the UI one by one. Or set it according to your need.